# Last digit of $2^{24!}$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

What is the last digit of:

$2^{24!}$

I am not sure how to approach this problem as 24! is extremely large. Normally I would notice the cyclic nature of powers of 2 i.e. $2^1 = 2, 2^2 = 4, 2^3 = 8, 2^4 = 16, 2^5 = 32$ and so the last digit cycles so all we need to do is determine $n$ mod $4$.

But not sure how to do it with such a large number, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$24!=1\times2\times\ldots\times10\times\ldots\times20\times \ldots\times 24=100\times(??)\equiv4 \mod{4}$$
Clearly the last digits are $00$ for $24!$, so the last digit of $2^{24!}$ is same as $2^4$ which is $6$.

Comment: ...which is $6$.

Comment: Haha, sorry for that. Edit is made.

Comment: so would $2^{120!}$ for example also be 6?

Comment: $2^{n!}$ has last digit $6$ for all $n \ge 4$.

Comment: Yes. In general $4|n!$ for all $n\geq4$, as @Lord_Farin says.